# System() call doesn't work inside a service thread? Linux

Tags: linux, audio, makefile, raspberry-pi, systemd

Goodday guys,
I'm facing a little problem when running my service on Linux.
I made a C program where I set "Capture" to muted (or unmuted) whenever I get the string "UN/MUTE",
I put this logic inside a thread for several reasons.
I don't understand why the program works when I run it directly (./nameexec or makerun), but not when I run it as a service.

Am I missing something?

**My service structure:**

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
After=pulseaudio.service alsa-state.service sound.target
Requires=network.target sound.target
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=+/home/pi/.../nameexec
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
KillMode=process   
User=pi
Group=audio                     
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**My thread:**

```
[...]
int s;
[...]
void ServerCheckConnection(void *threadarg)
{
    Server_Socket();
    cnctd = 0;
    while(cnctd == 0) //Not connected
    {           
        Server_Connection();
        while(cnctd == 1) //Connected
        {           
            while(1)
            {
                ctrl = read(ClientSocket, client_message, sizeof(client_message));
                if(ctrl <= 0)
                {
                    cnctd = 0;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(strcmp(client_message, "MUTE") == 0)
                    {
                        s = system("sudo amixer set Capture nocap"); //Console command - mute
                    }
                    
                    if(strcmp(client_message, "UNMUTE") == 0)
                    {
                        s = system("sudo amixer set Capture cap"); //Console command - unmute
                    }
                    memset(client_message, 0, sizeof(client_message));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
[...]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: For one thing, you probably shouldn't be using `sudo` in the service.  Instead, the service should run as a user that has sufficient privilege to do what it needs to do.

Comment: Additionally, when run as a service, the program is unlikely to have the same environment as when you run it directly.  It may therefore be that the `amixer` command is not in its search path when it run via a systemd service.

Comment: "amixer set Capture cap" is the only system call that doesn't work. 
I have in another part of the same program another system call "aplay /abspath/play.wav" that works instead. Could be the name "Capture"? Normally, when I run this command it gives me an output string but I don't know how to get it in my program.

Comment: Terminology: calling the `system()` function is not a "system call".  That term refers to exercising one of the kernel's (system's) entry points to request services, or, a bit more loosely, to calling one of the many C library functions that serve specifically as wrappers for making such requests.  The `system()` function is not one of those functions.

Comment: If the program elsewhere successfully runs `amixer` via the `system()` function, but it fails consistently when trying to exercise the "set" subcommand to modify the "Capture" property, then it seems most likely that `amixer` has an undocumented context dependency.  It may be a sensitivity to the real UID or real GID as which it runs.  I can also imagine that `amixer` might intentionally deny requests to twiddle the capture mode if they do not come from a live user session.  All of this is speculative, however.

Comment: Do note also, however, that it would be more typical for a service such as you are preparing to use the alsa API (alsa-lib) to interact directly with it, as opposed to going throug amixer.